# Can I add a custom button using Microsoft Band's SDK?

Tags: microsoft-band

I've been toying with the Microsoft Band SDK all morning. I've figured out how to send notifications, and read sensor data.

However, I've been trying to add buttons with 'click handlers', so that i can add custom buttons, and trigger actions upon click/tap.

I can not figure out how to do this. Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: look like unfortunately it is not included in the sdk at the moment. from http://www.i-programmer.info/news/91-hardware/8325-microsoft-band-gets-an-sdk.html The SDK misses quite a few features such as no keyboard or voice input, no access to touch events or the action button, but it does give you access to the main sensors and data which many fitness bands keep you well away from.

Comment: As Jeff points out below, this is now possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The just released version of the Band SDK allows an application to create custom tile page layouts that can include buttons. The application will be notified when the user presses a button in its tile.

Go to http://developer.microsoftband.com/ , use the "Documentation" link to view the PDF, and see section 2.7 "Customizing Tile Layouts" and section 2.8 "Handling Custom Tile Events".